# Mapping lack of understanding

Tags: mapping, solidity, smartcontracts

I read a lot about this topic and I understand it quit good.
But, the only thing I don't understand is how in functions developers use it without a function that insert the values.
example:

```
mapping (uint256=>address) public IdToAddress;
```

after they defines it I see that they are using in functions like:

```
function HolderOfNFT(Uint256 Id) public returns (address) {
 return IdToAddress[Id];
```

}

How the mapping has value in the Id key that points to the right address?
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All mapping values are empty by default.

So unless the value is set somewhere in the code, your example would return `address(0)` for any `Id`.

You can assign a mapping value the same way as you'd assign it to an array. Examples:

```
IdToAddress[Id] = address(0x123);
```

```
function transfer(address _recipient, uint256 _id) public {
    require(IdToAddress[_id] == msg.sender, "You're not the current token owner");
    IdToAddress[_id] = _recipient;
}
```